# NuxtJS with Tailwindcss gradient not working in production but working in local

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css

Using NuxtJS with pre-installed tailwindcss

And having some gradients backgrounds classes like "bg-gradient-to-r from-pink-500 via-red-500 to-yellow-500"

These gradient color classes don't seem to work in production mode but working fine in local.